# Adding new 2 column segment in resume/cv

Tags: xetex, cv

I was creating a new CV using the [Freeman CV Template used](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/freeman-cv)), Is it possible to add a new section after the given details so that I can add declaration which will span over both the columns. I also want to align both the columns, such that, both the columns are ending on the same vertical level. I'm a beginner in LaTeX. Please help me out.

Comment: You've posted the direct URL to your Overleaf project, and other users won't be able to access your project through it. It may be better to post the URL where the template was downloaded from (e.g. from the Overleaf Gallery page or from the original source website), and then use some screenshots to indicate where you'd like to add/change things, so that tex.sx users have more details on this page itself about what you'd like to do.

Comment: http://www.latextemplates.com/template/freeman-cv. This is the link from which I got the template. @LianTzeLim

Comment: I'm really stuck. Any possible solutions? @LianTzeLim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. Add this code after `\end{parcol}`

`\end{paracol}
\medskip
\hline
\section{Declaration}
\par
{\hspace{1cm} I hereby declare that the details furnished above are true and correct to the best of my knowledge and belief and I undertake to inform of changed therein, immediately.}`

Answer (score 2):

This template uses the `paracol` package and environment to set its contents *in parallel* in two columns.

Any material added after the `\end{paracol}` will therefore occupy the full width of the text block.

However the `paracol` can't be "balanced" by design: its purpose is to first lay out all the contents in the first column (i.e. before `\switchcolumn`), splitting across pages if necessary. Then after `\switchcolumn` it goes back to the beginning where the `paracol` environment started, and proceeds to lay out the contents in the second column, again splitting across pages if necessary.